# How to make a side menu in Vaadin 13?

Tags: vaadin, sidebar, side-menu

Can anyone show me how to create a side menu in Vaadin 13?
I’ve tried it with the normal App layout, but I can’t put it to the side like I want it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, please provide the code and explain why it does not what you want (e.g. errors, exceptions, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awesome Addon from the vaadin directory:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/app-layout-add-on

It's a responsive Sidebar.

You just need to add following dependency in your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.appreciated</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-layout-addon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Under https://github.com/appreciated/vaadin-app-layout you can find some example code.

Friendly Greetings

Danilo Jakob